# Getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CalculateGeometryAttributes_management'?

Tags: arcpy, attributeerror

I am trying to calculate the area for my grid cells. For that, I give the 
following command

`arcpy.CalculateGeometryAttributes_management(union, "AREA")`

Here, `union` is my grid and I need to make a new field to store the area. I am getting the following error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'CalculateGeometryAttributes_management'
```

Comment: What version of ArcGIS do you have? The arcpy.CalculateGeometryAttributes_management is **only available in ArcGIS desktop 10.6 and Pro** if you have 10.5 or earlier then the instruction isn't recognized, hence the error message saying *'arcpy doesn't have this attribute you've asked for'*.

Comment: It's [Add Geometry Attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm) you should be using, that came in at version 10.3.

Comment: Make sure you use the documentation associated with the version of ArcGIS you are using. If attempt to choose "Other versions" you'll see that 10.3-10.5 are greyed out, which indicates that this command was introduced at 10.6

Answer (score 2):

Prior to ArcGIS 10.6 to add and calculate an area you add the field with [arcpy.AddField_management](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000047000000), type of float or double then use [arcpy.CalculateField_management](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000) [with the geometry attributes](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s00000027000000). [See examples here.](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/)

The workflow looks like this:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(Union,'AREA','DOUBLE')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Union,'AREA','!shape.area!','PYTHON')
```

As near as I can tell the 10.6 [CalculateGeometryAttributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm) is a shortcut to executing the two instructions required in previous versions.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but what are !shape.area! and PYTHON for?

Comment: PYTHON says to use python syntax for the calculation statement, the fields are surrounded by exclamation marks - this is one of the few times that field delimiters are important. !shape! is the geometry of the row, the field is of type geometry https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000070000000 which has a property *area* in the same units as the feature class coordinate system, it's a bit more complicated but not impossible to calculate the area in a different coordinate system if needed.